# wix: setting RegistryKey Root HKMU

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer

If I set the root attribute to HKMU in the RegistryKey, how do I know where to search (RegistrySearch root = HKCU or HKLM )in my registry for my RegistryValue. Or how can i set the root value dynamically?

Comment: For the clueless like me: [Wix resolves HKMU](http://wix.mindcapers.com/wiki/HKMU_registry_key) to HKLM if you tick 'for all users' in the installer or to HKCU if you don't. It's not something you can find in regedit or winreg.h

Comment: HKMU switches between hklm and hkcu depending on machine or user installation.

Comment: thanks for your answers!! But that's my "problem" depending what the person choose (user or machine installation). How do i know, when I uninstall the app where i should look for my property which was stored in the registry, depending on which kind of installation mode ran. Because in the RegistrySearch I can't choose HKMU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually this is done by using two searches with the same property: one search for HKLM and another one for HKCU.

The following scenarios can then occur:

- first search finds the value and sets the property; in this case the second search result is ignored because its property was already sets by the first search
- second search find the value and sets the property
- both searches find nothing and the property is empty

Comment: maybe that is not working in domains with roaming data. if one system is installed as machine and an other system is installed per user. but that depends on the kind of data.

Comment: What if a user don't have permissions to get HKLM? Will it raise an exception or UAC request or something else?

Comment: The HKLM search will result in a UAC prompt, if the user is not an administrator!  If the user cancels the prompt, the instal is aborted.  This makes this method useless for dealing with perMachine/perUser in the same msi package.

Answer (score 1):

my quick idea you are requesting the install location of that component from the installer.

this can done via installer api. if you are using the on demand stuff, you have to query the installer anyway.

you can use the MsiGetComponentPathEx of MsiGetComponentPath function for that:

- [MsiGetComponentPathEx  in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408006%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [MsiGetComponentPath in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370112%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)